# NoSuchElementException - How to fix it

Tags: java

Code:

```
public void menuAdmin() throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Paciente paciente;
    int choice;

//  try {
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion:");
            System.out.println("1 - Buscar paciente por DNI");
            System.out.println("2- Crear nuevo paciente");
            System.out.println("3- Modificar un paciente");
            System.out.println("4- Eliminar paciente");
            System.out.println("5- Salir");
            choice = input.nextInt();     //HERE IS THE ISSUE
        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 5);

        switch (choice) {

        case 1:

            paciente = (Paciente) func.buscarPacienteDni();
            System.out.println();   
            if (paciente == null){
                menuAdmin();
            }else{
            menuX(paciente.getIdUser());
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            func.registrarse();
            menuAdmin();
            break;

        case 3:
            func.modifPaciente();
            break;

        case 4:
            func.elimPaciente();
            break;


        case 5: func.exit();
              }
//  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
//  }
    input.close();
}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at clases_basicas.Opciones.menuAdmin(Opciones.java:58)
at clases_basicas.Opciones.menuAdmin(Opciones.java:68)
at clases_basicas.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Reading a few posts about this, I understand what is happening. Switch is working with a parameter which could be empty, so I should use **input.hasNextInt()** to first check that. I tried to do a while to check this, but just keeps looping.

How can I prevent User to select a invalid and also check that nextInt() is not empty?

Also, I read about input.close could be the problem, so when it's supposed to close the Scanner? At the end of each method or somewhere else?

Comment: Never close a `Scanner` that is wrapping `System.in`. `System.in` is a global variable. So if you close it, and then try and read from it, it will immediately return.

Comment: Typically you don't close `System.in`. If you didn't open a resource, you shouldnt close it

Comment: So I should open only 1 Scanner for all the class?

Comment: @ChristianGallelli That is an interesting conclusion. It's not necessary. But it's not wrong. Just don't close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in` (but passing a `Scanner` to your methods isn't bad - you might decide to read from a `File` in version 2 after all).

Comment: Thanks, I tried local Scanner for the methods in first menu but no input.close and for now, it's working! Thanks